# Store the value of an if statement to some other variable in C

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I have a code block in c.

```
for (int e = 2; e < T; e++) {
   if (gcd(T, e) == 1)
      break;
}
```

So this code block calls `gcd` and finds out the gcd of (T,e). Now suppose T = 100. I want to record the value of `e` for which `gcd(T, e) == 1`.  How could I store the value of `e` in some other variable like `a` for which `gcd(T, e) == 1`.

Comment: Create some other variable, `a`, before the loop and assign it the value that you want to preserve (`if (gcd(T, e) == 1) { a = e; break; }`)?  Or define `e` outside the loop and then you can use it after the loop.

Comment: You are calculating the smallest coprime number, `e`, to `T`, where `1 < e`; this is the smallest number not in the prime factorization of `T`, a fact which you could use to improve the run-time of this algorithm.

Comment: @Neil: Re “this is the smallest number not in the prime factorization of `T`”: That should say the smallest prime not in the prime factorization. For `T` = 12, both 0 and 4 are numbers not in the prime factorization of `T`, but the desired result is 5.